# how to handle if a key in a list does not exist for some records in python?

Tags: python, list, key-value

I have two records for `a` as below -

```
a = {"id": 109501179854432111, "created_at": "2022-12-12T14:30:04+00:00","emojis": [], "media_attachments": [], "mentions": [], "tags": [], "emojis": [], "card": null, "poll": null}

a = {"id": 109501179854432111, "created_at": "2022-12-12T14:30:04+00:00","emojis": [], "fields": []}, "media_attachments": [], "mentions": [], "tags": [], "emojis": [], "card": null, "poll": null,"application":{"name":"Metatext","website":null}}
```

I have used below approach if condition to check the existence of the key and fetch its value -

```
if a['application']:
   print(a['application'])
```

This works well for second `a` record but gives below error for first `a` record -

```
 if a['application']:
KeyError: 'application'
```

How can we check and handle both the cases?
Please help.

Comment: Try `if 'application' in a`...

Comment: Don't access to it directly, try something like this `if 'application' is in a.keys()`

Comment: Note that you should use `None` in your dictionaries as Null will be rejected.

Comment: Simply try using `try` and `except` if you want a basic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `.get` method to provide default value to be used when key is missing as follows

```
a = {"name":"John Doe","age":27}
b = {"name":"Jane Done"}
print(a.get("age","unknown"))  # 27
print(b.get("age","unknown"))  # unknown
```

Observe that `a` and `b` are `dict`s (associative arrays if you insist at language-agnostic terminology) not `list`s.